# Delphi 2010 App loading a Delphi 7 DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2010

My app is compiled with Delphi 2010. That app loads a Delphi 7 compiled DLL which loads a Delphi 2010 compiled DLL.

```
D2010 app LOADS D7 DLL LOADS D2010 DLL
```

The exported functions of the D7 DLL uses `Widestrings` and the exported functions of the Delphi 2010 DLL use `strings`.

As we all know, `strings` in Delphi 2010 are Unicode (2 bytes) and in Delphi 7 they are Ansi (1 byte).

All my tests show me that it is working despite the fact that it should not. I am wondering:

Why is it working?

What can go wrong?

Which memory manager should I use (Delphi 2010 or Delphi 7 memory manager DLL)

Comment: It's a bug that this is working? ;-)

Comment: @Pol no, its is not. I am just trying to understand why it does work.

Comment: Not anwer to your question, but you can use WideString on both sides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D2009 and D2010, the RTL has logic in place (the compiler's `{$STRINGCHECKS ON}` directive) that allows an `AnsiString` to receive a Unicode payload, and a `UnicodeString` to receive an Ansi payload, across module boundaries, and then to perform a silent inline data conversion to the correct string type when the `AnsiString`/`UnicodeString` data is accessed. This is primarily to support legacy C++ projects that use event handlers with `AnsiString` parameters on the C++ side and `UnicodeString` variables on the Delphi side. In this case, it could also allow the D7 DLL to pass Ansi data to the D2010 DLL (the `STRINGCHECKS` directive was removed in XE, though).

I would expect the D2010 DLL to fail, though, because the memory layout of a `StrRec` record (which preceeds the character data in memory) changed in D2009 to add support for codepages, so the D7 DLL would not be allocating a D2010-compatible `StrRec` when passing an `AnsiString` value to a `UnicodeString` parameter in the D2010 DLL. I would expect the D2010 DLL to crash when it tries to access/free memory that does not exist.

This is yet another argument against ever passing `String` types across DLL boundaries.  Just don't do it, ever.  Use `WideString` or `PAnsiChar`/`PWideChar` instead.

Comment: +1 great answer. More on STRINGCHECKS http://www.micro-isv.asia/2010/09/stringchecks-gone-in-delphi-xe/